# How to make an XSD with list of variable elements(see description)

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to make a xsd that validates an XML that has a list with both Private and Corporate Associations.
My XSD looks like this:

```
<xsd:element name="PartnerAssociationList" type="PartnerAssociationList_t"/>

        <xsd:complexType name="PartnerAssociationList_t">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:choice>
                    <xsd:element name="PartnerPrivateAssociation" type="PartnerPrivateAssociation_t" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="PartnerRetailAssociation" type="PartnerRetailAssociation_t" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

Obviously this code only allows only one type Associations in XML to occur, while i need both. I know that i can do something like this

```
<xsd:complexType name="PartnerAssociationList_t">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Association" type="PartnerAssociation_t" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:sequence`enter code here`>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="PartnerAssociation_t">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:choice>
                    <xsd:element name="PartnerPrivateAssociation" type="PartnerPrivateAssociation_t"/>
                    <xsd:element name="PartnerRetailAssociation" type="PartnerRetailAssociation_t"/>
                </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

But i can't have that additional "Association" element in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support any mixture of private and retail associations then you just need to remove the `sequence` and make the `choice` unbounded:

```
<xsd:complexType name="PartnerAssociationList_t">
  <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:element name="PartnerPrivateAssociation" type="PartnerPrivateAssociation_t"/>
    <xsd:element name="PartnerRetailAssociation" type="PartnerRetailAssociation_t"/>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Your version allows a single choice between an unbounded number of private associations or an unbounded number of retail ones, whereas my version allows an unbounded number of "items" where each item is either private or retail.

Comment: Wow, i didn't know that i can make choices unbounded. Thank you!